# multiple self join replacement

Tags: sql, join, self-join

**Want some replacement for multiple self join on a table. what is the maximum limit of self join on a table in SQL**

I have a table table_1 with columns as:

```
uid number(10),
a_name nvarchar(20),
aaId number (10),
```

where **unique constraint** is there on **combination of uid and aaId.**

data present in table is like.
for each aaId there are around 90 Uid's.

now my query is like

```
select aaId from table_1 
  inner join table_1 t1 on t1.uid=9 and t1.a_name like 'a'  
  inner join table_1 t2 on t2.uid=8 and t2.a_name like 'ab'  
  inner join table_1 t3 on t3.uid=7 and t3.a_name like 'ac'
```

My problem is 
number of inner join has increased to 90 .
as rows in table is around 2 lakh will this query work .
Or if there is anything else I can do to replace this large number of self joins.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using inner join? what purpose is it serving, what data are you trying to extract?

Comment: Yes, please explain what you're trying to do.  It's not at all obvious from your code.  I'm guessing that you're trying to select only the aaIds that have a complete set of records in the table, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: An example (a data sample and the expected results for it) would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you use the WHERE part with OR statement?

```
select aaId from table_1 
WHERE (table_1.uid=9 and table_1.a_name like 'a') OR 
(table_1.uid=8 and table_1.a_name like 'ab') OR
(table_1.uid=7 and table_1.a_name like 'ac')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query which is used self join and required conditions

select aaId from table_1 t1, table_1 t2
where (t1.uid=9 and t2.a_name like 'a') or
(t1.uid=8 and t2.a_name like 'ab')